# scipy misc.imread() returns FileNotFound Error in Python3

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I am trying to read an image file as an ndarray in python using misc.imread() in the Anaconda distribution for Python3 as:

```
from scipy import misc
photo_arr = misc.imread('sd-3layers.jpg')
```

But even though the image file is present in the anaconda directory itself, it returns FileNotFound error: no such file or directory.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sd-3layers.jpg'
```

Also, PIL is installed.

Comment: Stupid question, but: are you sure that the file is there? And that you're in the same directory when you're calling the script? Try with a full file path, that should fix the latter. Or use a simple name such as `foo.jpg` so that you're not tricked by weird characters. Because I can't reproduce your issue on linux.

Comment: It's also possible that your image has a different format than you think or has a double extension, i.e. `file.jpg.jpg` or maybe it's `file.jpeg`, etc.